# Expand using javascript

Tags: javascript

Not sure why this isn't working? Am I missing something? Just looking for the button when clicked to expand the content down.

HTML:

```
<button id="reviews">Click to see more reviews!</button>
<div id="content">
    <ul id="content-list">
        <li>Our kids had an amazing time in the Martian Hunt workshop! - Blake</li>
        <li>We didn't know what to expect but the staff were friendly and made our stay memorable - Casey</li>
        <li>The room was amazing and we had some great views of the landscape - Steve</li>
        <li>Will definitely be coming back for my anniversary! - James</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#reviews {
    font-size: 1rem;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #bb4949;
    padding: 1px 30px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 500;
    justify-content: center;
}

#content {
    background:#ccc;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 300ms;
    max-height: 0;
}

#content.open {
    max-height: 100px;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$(function() {
  var r = $("#reviews");
  var c = $("#content");
  var l = $("#content-list");
  r.click(function() {
    c.toggleClass('open');
  });
});
```

Otherwise, happy to hear suggestions on another simple way to get this to expand! Thank you

Comment: Its working for me. Make sure you have included `jQuery` in your project.

Comment: Check browser console for any error by pressing f12 and going to console tab. Also make sure to include jQuery before the code block

Comment: [Open the Developer Tools](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch002153.htm) and tell us if there are any errors

Comment: Also make sure you've imported the JavaScript file inside of a `<script>` tag

Comment: Why don't you use `$(documen).ready(function() {/*your code*/})` ?

Comment: Works perfectly for me. I copied your example in the following stackblitz, you can check it working here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/jquery-dxxxur
As other people have suggested check for console errors and make sure you imported jquery

Comment: @Dani what do you mean? As in put it as the first line of my javascript code?

Comment: @TechySharnav I'm fairlly new to JavaScript, how do I import the JQuery or link it? So it cant work in the usual JavaScript (js) file?

Comment: Please post all your code, specifically all HTML file

Comment: @dekiv Copy Paste the following script tag into head of HTML your html file (before the body). `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>`

Comment: @TechySharnav thanks for that! Yes that has worked - what does that code do and how did it make it work?

Comment: @dekiv is it the whole content of your js file ? Do you import it via ajax ?

Comment: @dekiv It includes the `jQuery` Library into the project.

Comment: @TechySharnav ok - I will have to explain this to my group so I was wondering what it meant. Is it specifically my library or..? Sorry I don't really get it.

Comment: @dekiv Yes, it is specifically your library. You are using an external library, so you need to include it in the project. `cdnjs.com` is site which hosts most of the libraries online. You can find other libraries there as well. Hope this Answers your question. :)

Comment: @TechySharnav legend!

Answer (score 0):

I am reading carefully that you having the suspected issue. I think you should include the jquery parsing statement and use the `$(document).ready(function(){})` function.

So, I think that it must be including in HTML code context and changing code in JS following below.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
$(document).ready(function (){
  var r = $("#reviews");
  var c = $("#content");
  var l = $("#content-list");
  r.click(function () {
     c.toggleClass('open');
  });
});
```

Comment: Hey, i tried it but it still doesnt work?

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me.

```js
$(function() {
  var r = $("#reviews");
  var c = $("#content");
  var l = $("#content-list");
  r.click(function() {
    c.toggleClass('open');
  });
});
```

```css
#reviews {
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #bb4949;
  padding: 1px 30px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  justify-content: center;
}

#content {
  background: #ccc;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 300ms;
  max-height: 0;
}

#content.open {
  max-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="reviews">Click to see more reviews!</button>
<div id="content">
  <ul id="content-list">
    <li>Our kids had an amazing time in the Martian Hunt workshop! - Blake</li>
    <li>We didn't know what to expect but the staff were friendly and made our stay memorable - Casey</li>
    <li>The room was amazing and we had some great views of the landscape - Steve</li>
    <li>Will definitely be coming back for my anniversary! - James</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

You are probably running into issues where JQuery is not loaded properly, or your script is included wrong. Make sure to include JQuery in the head of your document, like so:

```html
<head>
  <!-- ... -->
  <script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4="
    crossorigin="anonymous"
  ></script>
  <!-- ... -->
</head>
```

Also make sure your script itself is included. If not, put it at the bottom of the body of your document:

```html
<body>
  <!-- ... -->
  <script src="./script.js"></script> <!-- the filename of your script -->
</body>
```

or...

```html
<body>
  <!-- ... -->
  <script>
  // JS goes here
  $(function() {
    var r = $("#reviews");
    var c = $("#content");
    var l = $("#content-list");
    r.click(function() {
      c.toggleClass('open');
    });
  });
  </script>
</body>
```

Your whole structure should look like this:

**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- ... (maybe a <title> or some <meta> tags) -->
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="reviews">Click to see more reviews!</button>
    <div id="content">
      <ul id="content-list">
        <li>
          Our kids had an amazing time in the Martian Hunt 
          workshop! - Blake
        </li>
        <li>
          We didn't know what to expect but the staff were
          friendly and made our stay memorable - Casey
        </li>
        <li>
          The room was amazing and we had some great views of
          the landscape - Steve
        </li>
        <li>
          Will definitely be coming back for my anniversary!
          - James
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <script src="./script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**style.css**

```css
#reviews {
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #bb4949;
  padding: 1px 30px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  justify-content: center;
}

#content {
  background: #ccc;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 300ms;
  max-height: 0;
}

#content.open {
  max-height: 100px;
}
```

**script.js**

```js
$(function() {
  var r = $("#reviews");
  var c = $("#content");
  var l = $("#content-list");
  r.click(function() {
    c.toggleClass('open');
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Although I tried it and it still doesnt work. I added the HTML as you did above, but still nothing

Comment: @dekiv Weird... I have no clue what your problem is, sorry! Maybe try checking the browser console?

Answer (score 0):

You are using an external library, `jQuery` which is mostly used for `DOM` operations.
As it is external library, you need to include it into your project, so that you can use it.
There are many sites distributing these libraries. I am using `cdnjs.com` here.

```js
$(function() {
  var r = $("#reviews");
  var c = $("#content");
  var l = $("#content-list");
  r.click(function() {
    c.toggleClass('open');
  });
});
```

```css
#reviews {
    font-size: 1rem;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #bb4949;
    padding: 1px 30px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 500;
    justify-content: center;
}

#content {
    background:#ccc;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 300ms;
    max-height: 0;
}

#content.open {
    max-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<button id="reviews">Click to see more reviews!</button>
<div id="content">
  <ul id="content-list">
    <li>Our kids had an amazing time in the Martian Hunt workshop! - Blake</li>
    <li>We didn't know what to expect but the staff were friendly and made our stay memorable - Casey</li>
    <li>The room was amazing and we had some great views of the landscape - Steve</li>
    <li>Will definitely be coming back for my anniversary! - James</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```